# Objective C Method signatures problem

Tags: objective-c, methods

Hi I have declared a method in one of my classes called HttpWorker. The method declaration is

```
-(void) setRequestParameters:(NSString *)parameters iRequestCode:(double)iRequestCode initialSleep:(long)initialSleep;
```

I am using trying to call this method from another class called NetManager. I wrote following code for this

```
NSString *paramStr = @"jc=2";
HttpWorker *httpWorker = [[HttpWorker alloc] init];
double requestCode = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
[httpWorker setRequestParameters:paramStr iReqeustCode:requestCode  initialSleep:initialSleep];
```

But when I compile my code, xcode gives me following warning.

> warning: 'HttpWorker' may not respond to '-setRequestParameters:iRequestCode:initialSleep:'

Can anyone please tell me where i am wrong?
Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
iReqeustCode:
```

Should be:

```
iRequestCode:
```

Comment: Woww coool!! u were right man!! I am sooo dump!! thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Also you have not defined initialSleep. That should result in compile error!

Comment: intialSleep is an incoming argument to the method from where i am calling this setRequestParameters method.